# Как проверить наличие внешнего ключа у поля mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйе. Как проверить наличие внешнего ключа у поля определенной таблицы: 1. есть ли он? 2. для какого поля и таблицы он является внешним ключем?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`?

Comment: как вариант, но в программе такое действо не провернешь

Comment: А где в условии задачи были оговорены ограничения?

P.S. Тогда - `use information_schema` и читать оттуда (если права есть).

Answer (score 1):

Вот такие матюги нашлись:

1) Попроще (показывает `CONSTRAINT_NAME`, `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` и `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` для полей таблицы, если они есть):

```
use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
select 
  TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
from 
  KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where 
  TABLE_SCHEMA = "ИМЯ_БАЗЫ" 
and 
  TABLE_NAME = "ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ" 
and 
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME is not NULL;
```

2) Понавороченней, показывает ВСЁ:

```
use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT 
  cols.TABLE_NAME, cols.COLUMN_NAME, cols.ORDINAL_POSITION,
  cols.COLUMN_DEFAULT, cols.IS_NULLABLE, cols.DATA_TYPE,
  cols.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,
  cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION, cols.NUMERIC_SCALE,
  cols.COLUMN_TYPE, cols.COLUMN_KEY, cols.EXTRA,
  cols.COLUMN_COMMENT, refs.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
  refs.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
  cRefs.UPDATE_RULE, cRefs.DELETE_RULE,
  links.TABLE_NAME, links.COLUMN_NAME,
  cLinks.UPDATE_RULE, cLinks.DELETE_RULE
FROM 
  `COLUMNS` as cols
LEFT JOIN `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS refs ON 
  refs.TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND refs.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND refs.TABLE_NAME=cols.TABLE_NAME
  AND refs.COLUMN_NAME=cols.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS cRefs ON 
  cRefs.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND cRefs.CONSTRAINT_NAME=refs.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT JOIN `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS links ON 
  links.TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND links.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND links.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME=cols.TABLE_NAME
  AND links.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME=cols.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS cLinks ON 
  cLinks.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND cLinks.CONSTRAINT_NAME=links.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE 
  cols.TABLE_SCHEMA="ИМЯ_БАЗЫ"
AND 
  cols.TABLE_NAME="ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ";
```